# How to find variance and probability from a uniformly distributed random variable?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Let $x$ be a random variable that describes the weight in pounds of a potato.
>   Assume $X\sim U(.5,1.5)$; that is, $X$ is uniformly distributed between $0.5$ and $1.5$ with average value $1$ pound.
>
> a) Find the variance $V(X)$;
>
> b) Find the probability that a sack of 100 potatoes will weigh less than $97$ pounds?

So to get the variance I need to find the expected value. And that would be...

\begin{equation}
  fx(t)dt = ft(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    0.5, \quad x < 0.5, \\
    1.5, \quad 0.5 < x < 1.5\quad (?)
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Sorry. I've only done the uniform distribution of $(0,1)$.

Comment: As a check, your question says the average or expected value of one potato should be $1$ pound.  And so of one hundred potatoes $100$ pounds.  Your formula would be easier to read using $\LaTeX$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may recall that the PDF of the continuous uniform distribution over $[a,b]$  is
$$
  f(x)=\begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{b - a} & \mathrm{for}\ a \le x \le b, \\[8pt]
  0 & \mathrm{for}\ x<a\ \mathrm{or}\ x>b,
  \end{cases}
$$ hence
$$
E(X)=\int_a^bxf(x)dx=\int_a^b \frac{x}{b-a}dx=?
$$
$$
V(X)=\int_a^bx^2f(x)dx-(E(X))^2=\int_a^b \frac{x^2}{b-a}dx-(E(X))^2=?
$$

> Here $a=\frac12$, $b=\frac32$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: So for a uniform distribution to have a value in the middle which is 1, then 2.25/2 - 0.25/2 is 1? Then the variance should be (x^3)/3 integrated between a and b =3.375/3- .125/3 - 1^2?

Comment: @Benny Onabach You may check your results here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)#Properties

Comment: Ohhh that really does simplifies everything. Thanks. Helps to know the proof too for double checking.

Comment: @Benny Onabach You are welcome.

Comment: $P(X\le 0.97)=\int_{0.5}^{0.97} \frac{1}{1}dx=0.47$.

Comment: Thanks! And if I wanted to say more than 97 pounds the integral would be 0.97 to 1.5?

Comment: @Benny Onabach Exactly.

Comment: I suspect not: the hundred potatoes are presumably independently distributed rather than identical

Comment: @Henry What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $a>0$ and $U$ has uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ then $X:=aU+b$ has uniform distribution on $(b,a+b)$.

Backwards: if $X$ has uniform distribution on $(b,a+b)$ then $U:=\frac{X-b}{a}$ has uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.